# How to display the first three logos wait for some second and display next three logos with infinite loop?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have 9 logos as of now and that logo I am displaying in the list order. Now what I am doing is, I have to display the first 3 logos and wait for some second then hide that 3 logos and display the next 3 logos again wait for some second, and display the next 3 logos. I need infinite this.

For example:

```
On the page load display first 3 logo

1 2 3

//wait for the second

1 2 3   // hide this
4 5 6   // display this
7 8 9   // hide this

//wait for second  
1 2 3   // hide this
4 5 6   // hide this
7 8 9   // display this

// wait for second
1 2 3   // display this
4 5 6   // hide this
7 8 9   // hide this

I need infinite.
```

I tried this code but it's not working.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

ul li img {
  width: 250px;
}


/*Animated Logos*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.row--animated li:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

.row--animated li:nth-child(4),
.row--animated li:nth-child(5),
.row--animated li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.row--animated li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  animation-duration: 8s;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row--animated">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 1" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 2" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 3" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 4" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 5" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 6" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 7" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 8" /></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 9" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: are you looking for CSS only solution? is ok to have javascript/jQuery?

Comment: @ROOT, Can you help me with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, sure I will check it now.

Comment: @Neren, sorry my friend I have something urgent, I can't work on it  if its not urgent thing for I will have a look at it later.

Comment: @ROOT, No problem, I'll wait for your reply. Stay safe stay healthy.

Comment: the animation (your code) is working infinitely.

Comment: @jkalandarov Yes, My code is working infinite but not like my expected output.

Comment: @NarenVerma, sorry for the late response I really didn't have time, I posted an answer, its not done yet but can be starting point, really having urgent things to work on, if you run the snippet here make sure to have it on full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display-grid to force the elements in a single row.

And you can play with the properties of the animation to get this effect, but the duration of the animation should be the same for all the elements; what is changing from one to the other is the delay , to make then be at different stages of the animation:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  animation: fadeInSlow ease-in-out 6s infinite;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  grid-row: 1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInSlow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  21% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(5),
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

li:nth-child(7),
li:nth-child(8),
li:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="row--animated">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I manage the speed of fadein? Now it's running very fast

Comment: Change the percentages in the keyframes. I have added another keyframes set that fades slower

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I checked your updated answer. It's almost working till 9 but after 9 when it starts from 1 then I am getting some white bg or light opacity. You can check this image https://prnt.sc/se73v6

Comment: I believe it's solved now. I have added a keyframe for the 100% position

Comment: Yes, It's working perflect. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side

Comment: Happy that it helped

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: this snippet is what I think you want, note that I changed the HTML a bit so that I can manipulate the elements size and display, Implemented with CSS3 only, heavily inspire by this [codepen](https://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk):

```css
.slider {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100;
  height: auto;
}

.slide1 {
  animation: fade 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 8s infinite;
}
.slide2 {
  animation: fade2 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
  animation: fade3 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class='slider'>
      <div class='slide slide1'>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 3" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='slide slide2'>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 4" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 5" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 6" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='slide slide3'>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 7" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 8" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <img src="//placehold.it/300x280?text=Image 9" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the snippet. It's working. Is it possible to display all the logos in the same place?  I mean now it is displaying below. I tried position: absolute; to the li but it's not working.

Comment: yes, we can use `display: none;` instead of using opacity alone. let me check if I can do it.

Comment: @NarenVerma, this is a bit tricky one, I just want to ask if you want something like this then why not using a slider library?

Comment: @NarenVerma, I was able to achieve that using CSS only check it out, but I really recommend using a CSS slider library.

Comment: Do you have any plugin link for this? I checked your snippet. the arrangement is showing differently. I mean it is displaying 1 3 2, 3 6 5.    It is not infinite loop.

Comment: @NarenVerma, fixed are arrangement issue, for the loop, which browser are you using? for the libraries I don't have something in mind but [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)  might be good but its not purely CSS

Comment: Yes, Arrangement issue solved, I am using firefox. Run your code and don't touch cursor and wait till 9 then notice. If I touch the cursor then it starts from 1 again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213466/discussion-between-root-and-naren-verma).

Comment: Hi @ROOT, Your answer is also working but I found the best answer from vals. Upvote from my side.

Comment: @NarenVerma, its ok my friend :) I agree his answer is better.